# Is it possible in Javascript to get data only with a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript so maybe the question even doesn't make sense, but I wonder, before Promise and Fetch, how could one bring a data from another site?

Comment: The initial API looked like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest. Also google "callback hell"…

Comment: Before the Fetch API, developers used the `load` event of an [`XMLHttpRequest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Depends if it is the time when CORS was implemented or not. We used XMLHttpRequest or JSONP

Comment: Before the JSON object we even used `eval()` to parse a JSON object returned by `XMLHttpRequest` callback. Thank god we got better options now.